# Showing Users Previous Uploads to Choose from

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache

Not really sure where to start on this one and a day of google searches hasn't helped much.

I am working on a submission form where my logged in users can submit data in form fields and attach a number of files. These files should be available to the users across many submissions so as not to clog up my database with duplicate files and for user convenience not having to reupload files many times. The files will be mostly PDFs and word docs.

My question is, what is the most elegant solution to letting my user select a previously submitted file for their current submission and to "attach" or associate that file with multiple submissions? Some drop down box that shows previous uploads seems best and if you agree any code snippets would be super helpful.

I've decided to store the document files as blobs in their own table. I'm running php and MySQL on Linux with godaddy.

Thanks for advice on where to look for code samples in advance. Just haven't been able to find what I'm looking for. Is JavaScript necessary here?

Comment: show them a list of their files, with a check box to select if they want to attach it.

Comment: How would your users know which document specifically they should pick? Trying to display "documents" in such a format that users could pick one as "I would upload this one except it already exists here" sounds like an absolute nightmare. I mean, if you've got ten photos, that's one thing, but Word docs or PDFs or something are an absolute _beast_ to show in a browser, and the users won't have tools to help them figure out if their files are _identical_. Are you sure this is the way to go?

Comment: We're not search proxies for code samples, @Dev Newb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to handle file uploads is to simply store the file-name (which should be generated as unique) in the database and store the actual file in a directory.  That way, you won't have this issue of storing it in a BLOB.  Is there any reason you are doing that over this method?

Now, if you output a SELECT form element with a list of filenames stored in the database, a user can simply select one and all you need to do is store that filename in the new row.  Then, all rows that point to that file name will point to the same file, with no need to upload it.

If you want to allow multiple file uploads or "attachments" in this case, then you are going to need to create a one-to-many relationship in the database.  Each submission row will have many rows in another table that point to it, all referencing the corresponding files uploaded.  Such that any submission can have zero, 1, 2, or more files attached.  If they select files that already exist, great, just copy the username as stated above.  IF its a new file, then you should upload that file and add its name to the database.

Javascript isn't required but it would be nice - to add interactivity to your form.  If you want to allow for a user to click say, "Add New File", and have a new file upload form element appear.

Comment: Awesome advice. Thanks a ton, I read a ton on blob vs directory storage and just figured I had to pick one. So many arguments on both sides. Are you always for directory storage or do you think it's just very applicable to what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: I am basically against storing anything other than text in a database, and I would only deviate from that in very rare instances.  I've never had to in any of my projects, and the one time I did try it as a test, I actually had problems with it.   In this case it especially makes sense, since if you stored the file in the database you would need to create a whole new table just for storing files and it just over complicates things IMO.

Comment: Good advice. Didn't think it would be a big deal to add another referencing table and I'm loathe to go back and redesign my approach but I guess now is the time to do it before I'm too far.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a a `form`. Add a `select` with the list of files associated with that user. Add *another* form element that allows for file upload. Have all of your other stuff as normal.

On page view, populate the `select` with the filenames and put the row IDs for that file in the `<option value="file_id_xxx">...`.

In your server script, detect if a file was uploaded; if so, complete the process of storing the file and set the file reference as the associated file for the submission; if not, check that a file was selected from the dropdown and if so, save the reference from the `select` with previous uploaded files with the submission instead.

Javascript may help in disabling the `select` or file upload `input`, depending. But it's not necessary.

Comment: Sorry. Wasn't looking for full code. Just some pointers to get me going. U guys provided what I need to get me started. And in just a few minutes? This site kicks ass!